# $Z_n \backslash \{0\}$ splits into octets

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Let $n=8m+1, m\in\mathbb{N}$.  Does the set of nonzero elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ split into disjoint octets of the form $8_k=\{\pm a_k,\pm b_k,\pm a_k\pm b_k\}$?

The computer tells me it is possible if $n$ is not a multiple of 3, up to $n=113$. Larger $n$ have many solutions; $n=73$ has thousands of solutions.

For example, $Z_{17}\backslash\{0\}=\{\pm 1,\pm 4,\pm 1\pm 4\}\cup\{\pm 2,\pm 8,\pm 2\pm 8\}=\{\pm1,\pm4,\pm3.\pm5\}\cup\{\pm2,\pm8,\pm10,\pm6\}$

My motive is this: I am idly wondering whether there are $m$ patterns like this:

- Each pattern has an $n$-omino.  This $n$-omino has $n$ different coloured tiles, and it tiles the plane by translations.
- Different patterns may have different $n$-ominoes, but the same $n$ colours.
- Any two colours are adjacent (edge or corner) in exactly one pattern.
- A solution would be to colour tile at $(c,d)$ in pattern $k$ with colour $ca_k+db_k(\bmod n)$.

Comment: The natural condition would be that $8 | \varphi(n)$, right?

Comment: Ah. Why is that?

Comment: Oh, sorry, nonzero elements. The condition in the title is not the condition in the body; $\mathbb{Z}_n^{\times}$ is strictly smaller than the nonzero elements unless $n$ is prime.

Comment: I don't get it. $3$ is in ${\bf Z}_{17}^{\times}$, right? But $3\ne\pm1$, $3\ne\pm4$, $3\ne\pm2$, and $3\ne\pm8$. So what's going on here?

Comment: Sorry Qiaochu, the title is fixed now.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, 3=-1+4

Comment: That is, the first set contains $\pm 1,\pm 4,\pm3$ and $\pm5$.  The second set contains $\pm 2,\pm 8,\pm 10(=\pm 7)$ and $\pm6$.

Comment: Ah, I missed that there's no comma before the last $\pm$.

Comment: If $n$ is a multiple of 3, then each octet contains either 2 or 8 multiples of 3.  It turns out that $n$ must be $72k+9$ in this case.  There are solutions for $n=81$, but they don't work for my patterns because all the colours would be multiples of 3.

Comment: Suppose I replace $a_k\pm b_k$ with a random pair for each $a_k,b_k$.  There are $(4m)!/[2^mm!(2m)!]$ sets of $(a_k,b_k)$. The chance that any one set gives a solution is $(2m)!/(4m)^{2m}$, so the average number of solutions is $(4m)!/[m!32^mm^{2m}]$, which grows quickly with $m$.  In other words, I would expect lots of solutions, with no other particular reason.